# Error in Drupal index.php file

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7

I have installed Drupal 7.0 using cPanel in the domian space I purchased. The installation went in all good but when I tried to modify the content and log into the account I got the following error as in the screenshot.

[image]

The solution is for this says edit configure the index.php file in Apache. I cannot understand what should I put and where in that file.

I am new to Drupal and wordpress so could you anyone help me to solve this matter?

Thanks and regards,
Chiranthaka

Comment: looks like a `.htaccess` problem to me... do you have a .htaccess file in your root directory? if yes, did you change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission issue and I was able to solve it. Thanks anyway guys.